# Set default Custom Post Meta Value

Tags: post-meta, actions, wp-insert-post, save-post

I've tried almost anything and just can't get this to work.

I have a custom post type with a custom meta field and I want a default value to be added on when the Publish/Update/Save button is pressed.

I tried all kind of hooks `wp_insert_post`, `save_post`, `edit_post`..

```
add_action('save_post_post_type', 'set_default_meta', 10, 3);
```

And my function is:

```
function set_default_meta( $post_ID ) {

    $meta_value = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'meta_value', true);

    if ( $meta_value == '' && !wp_is_post_revision($post_ID) ) {
        add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'meta_value', 0, true );
    }
}
```

When I publish the post, the value is not saved. **However** whenI click View Post, the value is immediately saved.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta), because if the meta key already exists [`add_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) will do nothing if `$unique` is `true` and otherwise won't update neither, while `update_post_meta()`, well, it will update the value of a existing field or create it, if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you! I lost all day looking at hooks and stuff and lost all day.... you saved me another one.
Hmm, saw somewhere that priory should be at least one, but it's working without one.

Comment: My pleasure! Haven't we all overlooked something sometime.. Default priority is `10`, so not a problem, unless you want a specific one. @Ziik